# Android code, How do i measure the data usage of an App on mobile data

Tags: android, android-trafficstats

I want to measure the data consumed by my APP through mobile data[not Wifi] on each session launch.
The amount of data consumed on each session = amount of data consumed [at the end of session] - amount of data consumed [at the start of session].
But how can i get the amount of data consumed by my App on mobile data only.
API getUidRxBytes gets the number of bytes received across all the n/w interfaces, But i need for mobile data only.

Is there a way i can achieve this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-a-per-application-basis-on-android   It might help you.

Comment: @eminuluyol: that will give entire data consumed...

Comment: check this out as well and please try to combine both. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031295/android-how-to-know-internet-total-data-usage-per-day-through-wifi-and-mobile

Comment: @eminuluyol: The above link contains only the total number of bytes for all the app's. Its was not for specific app

Comment: In this sample this is only for youtube app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36702621/getting-mobile-data-usage-history-using-networkstatsmanager